# plot map with divergent colors according to 1 variable, saturation by another, ggplot2 not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, r-sf

I am working in R with a shapefile (a Large SpatialPoygonsDataFrame with 311 elements), the 1970 district map of India. I can plot a map in spplot by the value of a data column b_all (a district-specific regression coefficient) using:

```
brk1 = c(-130,  -5,    0,    5,  311)
spplot(distVDS_betas,zcol="b_all",at=brk1)
```

I can plot a similar map by another data column t_all (each regression coefficient's t-value):

```
brk2 = c(0,  1.645,    1.96,    53)
spplot(distVDS_betas,zcol="t_all",at=brk2)
```

What I would *like* to do instead is (a) plot the beta coefficients by a *divergent* color pattern (like orange-red going up fr/ zero, blue-purple going down fr/ zero) and then (b) saturate the colors by t-value. Can anyone help me do this?

I'm aware the ssplot is out-dated and I should be moving to ggplot2, and I'd love to learn how to use that. Tried following the code [here](https://r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html).  However, when I attempt to run this code:

```
ggplot(data = distVDS_betas) +
  geom_sf()
```

I get the error: `stat_sf() requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry.`

So I'm not even sure how to start with ggplot2 + sf.

Comment: You might try `distVDS_betas <- sf::st_as_sf(distVDS_betas)`. If that doesn’t work, could you post a small sample of your data using `dput()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your plotting relates to your data - your `ggplot` code is correct.

In the example you are following, notice that the `world` object is used, where `class(world)` is `sf`.

That means that when you inspect the `world` object, `world$geometry` gives information that `ggplot` uses to construct the map.

In your code, `distVDS_betas$geometry` does not exist because your data likely is not an `sf` object. This results in the error you are seeing and prevents you from plotting.

You have two options:

1. Convert your data to an object of class `sf`
2. Use a different `geom_*` that works with your object’s class

##### 1. Convert to ‘sf’

This is the easiest solution.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

distVDS_betas <- st_as_sf(distVDS_betas)

ggplot(data = distVDS_betas) +
    geom_sf()
```

##### 2. Use different `geom_*`

This solution depends on the structure of your data and the specific columns. This is just an example. For more info, look [here](https://tmieno2.github.io/R-as-GIS-for-Economists/geom-raster.html)

```
distVDS_betas |>
    ggplot() |>
    geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

Comment: This was very helpful! It doesnt get me to the larger goal obviously but I might get there myself now that I can use ggplot2. Thank you!